# How to call an external database google spreadsheet and overcome permissions via spreadsheetApp.openById() GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been searching around for ages to find a solution to this problem.

There are two spreadsheet files that I own. 1- [Recipe](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vLnmpBCIDD5aB1zBPlw7HTq69RAr2QpZuN83VJWtAQ4/edit#gid=870725857) 2- [Database](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JvQGDBY2Du0rtbHcQRdteLEGcWCSuS2JO7YinaC-tDc/edit#gid=0)

I want to pull the cost and volume of the ingredients from the database spreadsheet to inform the recipe spreadsheet and to automatically update when the database changes.

The error persists:

> Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

I realise that I cannot use `SpreadsheetApp.openById()` as it cannot call an external spreadsheet, that requires a function that allows permissions.

I've tried adding a custom menu item to ping the permissions check but that didn't cure the problem. I have also tried installing triggers that have solved the problem for other users, but to no avail. I have also adjusted the appsscript.json file to include the oauth scopes that are quoted in the error message but that hasn't changed the result. I have also made sure that the permissions on the files themselves are set to "anyone with the link can edit". The Google Sheets API is also installed.

There might be a glaring error in my code (I'm still pretty new to all this) that you fine folk might be able to point out to me.

```html
function myonOpen() {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Database')
  .addItem('Access', 'accessDB')
  .addToUi();
}
function accessDB() {
  SpreadsheetApp.openById('1JvQGDBY2Du0rtbHcQRdteLEGcWCSuS2JO7YinaC-tDc');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Database now active!');
}
```

Which then informs:

```html
function onOpen() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myOnEdit')
   .onEdit()
   .create();
}

/**
 * This function calls the database to give permission
 */

function myOnEdit(e){
   SpreadsheetApp.openById("1JvQGDBY2Du0rtbHcQRdteLEGcWCSuS2JO7YinaC-tDc");
}

/**
 * This fuction determines whether the ingredient is in the database & returns it's price point and breaks
 * @constructor
 * @customfunction
 *  */ 

function getCost(itemname){
  const ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1JvQGDBY2Du0rtbHcQRdteLEGcWCSuS2JO7YinaC-tDc");
  const ssh = ss1.getSheetByName('Cost');
  let tf = ssh.getRange('A1:A'+ ssh.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(itemname).findNext();
  return ssh.getRange(tf.getRow(),3).getValue();
}
```

If I'm barking up the wrong proverbial tree here and my custom functions just simply can't call external spreadsheets, what would be the workaround?

thanks in advance.

Comment: I will double check the fail line where SpreadsheetApp.openById(id) been called. Please make sure that file you are trying to access is not xlsx file format.

Comment: I've double checked, the file is not xlsx. I've changed the inverted commas to quote marks, still pinging the same error message. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Have you looked on your manifest to see if you have those scopes.  If not the just add it.

Comment: @Cooper I have added `.../userinfo.email` `.../script.scriptapp` & `.../spreadsheets` as well as `.../spreadsheets.readonly` there's no change.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. First, I would like to correctly understand your question. About `I want to pull the cost and volume of the ingredients from the database spreadsheet to inform the recipe spreadsheet and to automatically update when the database changes.`, in your situation, how is the database Spreadsheet changed? It's manually changed or automatically changed by a script or API?

Comment: @Tanaike It would be manually changed

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `I want to pull the cost and volume of the ingredients from the database spreadsheet to inform the recipe spreadsheet and to automatically update when the database changes.` and `It would be manually changed`, when "Database" sheet is manually edited, how about updating "Recipe" sheet by the installed OnEdit trigger in "Database" sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For trigger, instead of creating trigger by code, try installing it in the **Triggers** tab in your Apps Script. Once you save the trigger, it will pop up an authentication window, accept it and it will add the necessary scope to your project.

**Triggers Tab:**

[image]

**This is what your trigger setup should looks like:**

[image]

The `openById()` works and I tested it by creating 2 dummy spreadsheet, created `onEdit()` trigger in the 1st spreadsheet that prints the values in the 2nd spreadsheet.

**2nd spreadsheet:**

[image]

**Edited cell A1 in 1st spreadsheet:**

[image]

**Code in 1st spreadsheet:**

```
function myOnEdit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("2nd spreadsheet id");
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = sh.getRange("A1:A3").getValues();
  Logger.log(data);
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

### Reference:

- [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#new-editor)